# How can i count active projects in google sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, count, countif

I want to count how many active projects from for ex 01/01/2022 to 07/01/2022 if there's an end date then the projected is ended. If not then its still ongoing so don't count it.

[image]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A:A; B:B>="01/01/2022"; B:B<="07/01/2022"; C:C="")))
```